# aws s3 withRegion: Cannot resolve method 'withRegion(com.amazonaws.regions.Regions)'

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Trying to use aws s3 java api to create a AmazonS3ClientBuilder object and get error

Following this example:

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/java-s3-src-main-java-aws-example-s3-PutObject.java.html

Using AWS S3 SDK (Java):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.651</version>
</dependency>
```

Code:

```
AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.DEFAULT_REGION).build();
```

Error:

> Cannot resolve method 'withRegion(com.amazonaws.regions.Regions)'

Is this a bug or what am I doing wrong here?

I am using Java 8, the IntelliJ IDE and Maven for build tool ...

Update (15/10/19 @ 8:48PM AEST):

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>helloworld</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>A sample Hello World created for SAM CLI.</name>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.12</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ https://jsoup.org/ -->
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-lambda-java-events -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.651</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/sdk-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.651</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.20</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.1</version>
          <configuration>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: That is interesting, with your version of the dependency and your code snippet it works. Do you maybe have conflicting dependencies?

Comment: Martin - have updated the post with the full pom.xml

Comment: Martin - indeed - conflicting dependency on the DynamoDB library! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the issue is with `aws-java-sdk-dynamodb` dependency that you have added in your pom file. This has an internal dependency on `aws-java-sdk-s3`.

As the dependency version is `1.11.0`, so maybe this version of `aws-java-sdk-s3` does not have `withRegion` method in it (did not check though)

Try to upgrade the version to the latest and I guess your problem should get solved.

If you still see the same issue try to post the dependency tree result by issuing the command `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: Thanks Prasad. I updated the DynamoDB dependency to .651 (latest version) and it compiles!